# No signal for QT 5.3 Android GPS Positioning

Tags: android, qt, gps

I have started my very first Android 4.x / QT 5.3 project, which needs GPS data. I am basically following this example:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtpositioning-logfilepositionsource-example.html

which is the reason for not posting code so far -- which I will do when requested :-)

I have also already searched stackoverflow and considered this thread:

[QtPositioning error in Qt 5.3 RC on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737781/qtpositioning-error-in-qt-5-3-rc-on-android)

but I do not need satellite information at all.

However, my problem is that the app does not connect GPS signals and I am asking myself why. My only idea so far: The app has no right to access GPS data.

Any idea how I can get the app connect to and receive GPS position signals?

Thanks a lot for help. As mentioned, I can post code but I basically follow the above mentioned sample for starters.

Regards,
G.

Comment: Hm, I was hoping someone has done this successfully. Shall I post the code? However, as mentioned, it basically follows the above mentioned example from QT... Still seeking help, after having added the rights as shown by Mikolaj... :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you think it could be permissions problem, you should add permissions to manifest file. Try to find CreateAndroidManifest.xml button. In Projects->Build&Run you will see Deploy Configurations and Advanced Actions field. You will find the button there.

[image]

Then you should add `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` to Permissions field.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will give it a shot and let you know whether it worked!

Comment: Well, even though I think the permissions are necessary, it did not solve the problem. Thanks however for the useful hint! Upvote for it :-)